# add fonts to rdlc report by ttf font file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

i have a web application that client can select particular fonts for each part of rdlc report.. i dont have access to install fonts on the server... i get font names from a folder that upload on the server in a drop down list...

```
    Dim filesPath As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Fonts/"))
            Dim files As New List(Of ListItem)()
            For Each path__1 As String In filesPath
                files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(path__1)))
            Next
            ddTitleFont.DataSource = files
            ddTitleFont.DataBind()
```

i also tried this to pass font to rdlc report but no change happened

```
            Dim privateFonts As New PrivateFontCollection
    privateFonts.AddFontFile(ds.Tables("generateReport").Rows(0)("titleFont").ToString)
    Dim font As New System.Drawing.Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 12)
    Dim ptitlefont(0) As ReportParameter
    ptitlefont(0) = New ReportParameter("titleFont", font.Name)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {ptitlefont(0)})
```

i want to know if there is any solution to pass the font file to the rdlc report dynamically? or get the rdlc report font from a folder?